# Solutions for phpbb forum scrolling inside iframe?

Tags: php, jquery, html, iframe, phpbb

I'm working on the site: http://www.mastersofbackgammon.net/site/

If you click on the forum section you will see that the forum is displayed within an iframe.

The width is fine and it might look good now, however, when there are more threads or posts that exceed the height of the iframe, the only way to make it scrollable is by enabling scrolling on the iframe or by using middle mouse button. The problem is that iframe scrolling is visually unappealing.

I have also tried incorporating tinyscrollbar plugin on the phpbb forum itself, but with no success. The phpbb forum is a complicated system and the tinyscrollbar plugin cannot determine the final dimensions of the content.

Are there any solutions you guys could offer in such case? Maybe I could use something else instead of the iframe that would allow better scrolling design?

Comment: I would suggest *not* using iframes like this. Avoiding iframes in general is a good thing. If all else fails then start tweaking the `overflow` properties in your CSS and have fun with your 90s-throwback design.

Answer (score 2):

You can do some scrollbar styling, but I would suggest styling the forum to "fit" the look and feel of the site instead of trying to squeeze it into an iframe.

Comment: I have tried styling the scrollbar, but it still looks ugly. What do you mean when you say styling the forum to fit the site? Just making it completely separate? I will style it naturally, but my main concern currently is the sidebar.

Comment: What I mean is, I would build up (or modify) the phpbb theme to get "close" to the look and feel you are going for. This day and age, if people are still using forums (most seem to favor the blog) they tend to style them to fit with their site, instead of incorporating it in. I know it breaks the "stay consistent" rule of design, but if it has graphics and colors in common, it usually isn't too much of a stretch for people to realize that it is a styled phpbb board but is obviously related to your site. Honestly, they won't give it nearly as much thought as you already have I'm sure.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I will definitely redesign my forum, however I really want to get the scrollbar to work. It just seems to fit in perfectly with the site in terms of width and overall fit I believe. If only I knew how to fix the scrollbar.